# How to call R from .NET to save the result for using it programmatically at later point of time

Tags: .net, r, deployr

I am a .NET developer and new to R. we have an existing R script that generates annova decision tree in pdf format based on some input from excel. For a given criteria, people are manually parsing the tree and getting the node value and using it for their purposes. we need to automate the process now. I have two requirements
1. First, I need to make a call to R exe or library from .net program. 
2. The tree result of above call should be stored in database or filesystem, which needs to be retrived programmatically later point of time for use. 
3. At a later point of time, the above tree result needs to be loaded and parse the tree programmatically for the given criteria and get the node value.

I installed Microsoft R open and R studio, VSTS tools for R. Please let me know the tools/library and approach to achieve above requirement.

Comment: Have a look at https://rdotnet.codeplex.com/ to use R directly in C#. It may be simpler in some cases to just call it from the command line inside C# though (espeically if you're just running a script). Can't really answer how to parse it automatically without seeing the output.

Comment: Since you used the `deployr` tag, you likely know that you can use https://deployr.revolutionanalytics.com/docanddown/#rbroker from .NET. You need to install DeployR Open server, and then you can use the tools mentioned on the page, or use the REST api provided by the DeployR server directly.